# How to Re-Test a condition using If else statment Java android

Tags: java, android, if-statement

I am trying to set visibility of multiple items depending on the value of a variable and the value changes on button click.  I am very new at this.

my code looks something like this:

```
    int view = 1;

    if(view == 1) { Sets a bunch of visibilities}
    else if(view == 2) {Sets a different set of visibilities}
    else if(view ==3)...etc
```

Then I have an on click listener that increments the variable and I would like it to run through the IF statement again.

I am a hack trying to teach myself so just point me in the right direction not asking you to code it for me.  I am sure there is a better way to do this so just let me know what to look into and I will do my homework.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just do that code in the on click listener? or have the on click listener call that code?

Comment: The buttons are right and left arrows so the views they set depends on the the value of the variable.  How do I use the on click listener to call that code?

Comment: I think I am going to have to do it a different way and may have to do a little more homework before I can move forward.  I am stuck because I cannot take my code out of the onCreate method without messing up my findViewById variables.   Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your code is structured but this is how I would write could that needs to be rerun on every button click.

```
onClickListener(){
     id++ // Or whatever you need to do to the id value
     codeThatSetsTheView(id)

}

codeThatSetsTheView (int viewId){
    Switch (id)
         case 1: 
             view 1  //Enable the things for view 1 
             break; 
...


}
```

Answer (score 0):

why not use a switch statement instead of 300 IF/ELSE's?

```
switch(view) {
  case 1: // implement code
    break;
  case 2: // implement code
    break;
  .....
}
```

at a basic, you can use a class member variable to handle all that stuff some easier:

```
class myClass extends AnotherClass implements View.OnClickListener {
  private static int myVariable;

  public myClass(Context ctx, AttributeSet attr) {
    super(ctx,attr);

    setOnClickListener(this);
  }

  private void mySetterFunction() {
    myVariable = 1; // or set to what ever
  }

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    switch( myVariable ) {
      case 1: // do code here
        break;
      case 2: // do code here
        break;
      case 3: // do code here
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can do a number of things. I find that if I want to do something multiple times, it is a good idea to group those actions in a function. Also, if you want something done when something is clicked, that is the point of an onClick(View v) function in an OnClickListener.

Last thought- if you want something called more than once (like running through an if/else block), Call it more than once. Simply call your function as many times as you need to and do logic in between function calls (like incrementing a integer variable).